# How to display XML Object generated using JAXB UnMarshaller?

Tags: java, xml, object, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm using JAXB marshalling to create XML files, and it created successfully, and know i want to display these files using JAXB unMarshalling, here is the code i'm using:

```
public Object display(String fileName) throws IOException, JAXBException {

        XmlStructure object;
        File file = new File(fileName);
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XmlStructure.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnMarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        object = (XmlStructure) jaxbUnMarshaller.unmarshal(file);

        System.out.println(object.toString());
        return object;

    }
```

the previous code gives me that result:

```
com.nc.inotify.dp.xml.impl.XmlStructure@2916a6bf
```

and i changed the code with that:

```
    public Object display(String fileName) throws IOException, JAXBException {
XmlStructure object;
        File file = new File(fileName);
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XmlStructure.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        object = (XmlStructure) jaxbMarshaller.unmarshal(file);

        Marshaller jaxbMarshallerz = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshallerz.marshal(object, System.out);

        return object;
}
```

but it gives me that result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><XmlSource/>
```

and this is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<XmlSource>
<XmlConf>
    <hostName>weather.yahooapis.com</hostName>
    <parameters>
        <entry>
            <key>w</key>
            <value>2502265</value>
        </entry>
    </parameters>
    <URLPath>/forecastrss</URLPath>
    <urlProtocol>http</urlProtocol>
</XmlConf>
<XmlConf>
    <hostName>weather.yahooapis.com</hostName>
    <parameters>
        <entry>
            <key>w</key>
            <value>2553822</value>
        </entry>
    </parameters>
    <URLPath>/forecastrss</URLPath>
    <urlProtocol>http</urlProtocol>
</XmlConf>
</XmlSource>
```

**Update**
**NOTE**: i'm using more than one class in the marshaling process in order to get that form
The marshaling method:

```
public void add(String fileName) throws IOException, JAXBException,
            ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, TransformerException {

        this.fileName = fileName; 
        File temp = new File(tempName);
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XmlConfList.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        File source = new File(fileName);
        if (source.exists()) {

            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(object, temp);
            MergeXml merge = new MergeXml();
            merge.mergeXML(true, fileName, tempName, mainTag);
        } else {
            XmlStructure struct = new XmlStructure();
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(struct, source);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(object, temp);
            MergeXml merge = new MergeXml();
            merge.mergeXML(true, fileName, tempName, mainTag);
        }
        temp.delete();
    }
```

The MergeXml class:

```
public class MergeXml {

    private static final String YES = "yes";
    private static final String generalTag = "*";

    /**
     * This method used to merge XML old and new files together
     */
    public void mergeXML(boolean condition, String fileName, String tempName, String mainTag)
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException,
            TransformerException {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = null;
        Document doc = null;
        Document doc2 = null;

        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = db.parse(new File(fileName));
        doc2 = db.parse(new File(tempName));

        NodeList elements = doc.getElementsByTagName(mainTag);

        if (condition == true) {
            NodeList nodeList = doc2.getElementsByTagName(generalTag);

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                Node childNode = doc.adoptNode(node);

                elements.item(0).appendChild(childNode);
            }

        }

        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, YES);

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
        String xmlOutput = result.getWriter().toString();
        output.write(xmlOutput);
        output.close();

    }
}
```

The XmlStructure class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "XmlSource")
public class XmlStructure{

}
```

The XmlConf class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "XmlConf")
public class XmlConf extends XmlStructure {

    private String URLProtocol;
    private List<String> path = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String urlp;
    private Map<String, String> parameters;
    private String host;

    /**
     * This method used to retrieve the specified URL protocol
     * @return {@code String} 
     */
    public String getUrlProtocol() {
        return URLProtocol;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to store the URL protocol as String if the URL is a valid one
     * @param URL Protocol
     *            
     */
    @XmlElement
    public void setUrlProtocol(String URLProtocol) {
        this.URLProtocol = URLProtocol;
    }

    /**
     *  This method used to retrieve all the paths selected
     *         by the user in order to save
     * @return {@code List<String>}
     */
    @XmlElement
    public List<String> getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to store a new path added by the user
     * @param path
     *            
     */
    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path.add(path);
    }

    /**
     * This method used to set the path of the specified URL
     * @param urlp
     *            
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "URLPath")
    public void setUrlPath(String urlp) {
        this.urlp = urlp;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to retrieve the path of the specified URL
     * @return {@code String} 
     */
    public String getUrlPath() {
        return urlp;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to set the parameters of the specified URL
     * @param parameters
     *            
     */
    @XmlElementWrapper
    public void setParameters(Map<String, String> parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to retrieve the parameters
     *         of the specified URL
     * @return {@code Map<String, String>} 
     */
    public Map<String, String> getParameters() {
        return parameters;
    }

    /**
     *  This method used to set the host name of the specified URL
     * @param host
     *           
     */
    public void setHostName(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to retrieve the host name of the
     *         specified URL
     * @return {@code String} 
     */
    public String getHostName() {
        return host;
    }
}
```

The XmlConfList class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class XmlConfList {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "XmlSource")
    @XmlElement(name = "XmlConf")
    private List<XmlConf> list = null;

    public List<XmlConf> getList() {
        if(this.list == null)
            this.list = new ArrayList<>();
        return this.list;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the domain model look like?  I assume that the model did not marshal correctly because it wasn't populated during the unmarshal.

Comment: i just updated the question with all the info may be required, kindly have a look on it.